# Unterschied "sich in unsere/unserer Zeitung einzubringen"

Tags: grammar

Folgende zwei Sätze:

> Ich möchte Sie wieder ermutigen sich in *unserer* Zeitung einzubringen.
>
> Ich möchte Sie wieder ermutigen sich in *unsere* Zeitung einzubringen.

Beide Varianten *klingen* für mich möglich, jedoch bin ich mir erstens nicht sicher und zweitens wäre es sehr schön zu wissen, was grammatikalisch dahinter steckt.

Comment: Unabhängig vom eigentlichen Problem, finde ich, dass *wieder* falsch positioniert ist. Die Aussage, die ich beim ersten Lesen verstanden habe, ist, jemanden zu motivieren, der bereits Bestandteil war. Dann gehört das *wieder* aber zwischen *sich* und *in*. Sprich: *Ich möchte sie ermutigen, sich wieder in unserer Zeitung einzubringen.*

Comment: @Em1 Nehmen wir an es ist ein monatlich erscheinendes Blatt und man will (wiederholt) die Leser dazu ermutigen sich zu beteiligen. Also nicht die gleichen Leute *wieder* ermutigen, sondern *wiederholt* alle (auch Unbeteiligte) dazu ermutigen sich zu beteiligen. Puh.. war das irgendwie verständlich?

Comment: Ja, verständlich und überzeugend. Ich habe den Satz nur anders interpretiert, obwohl er grammatikalisch genau das aussagt, was du auch rüberbringen willst.

Comment: Zum eigentlichen Problem: Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einbringen#Bedeutung4a) wendet man hier wohl eher den Akkusativ an, sprich *in unsere Zeitung*. Ich wüsste aber nicht, was gegen den Dativ spricht. Persönlich tendiere ich zu *in unserer Zeitung*. Letztlich denke ich, ist beides gleichermaßen möglich.

Comment: @Em1 Das war letztlich auch der Konsensus zu dem wir hier gekommen sind. Ich persönlich tendiere auch mehr zu *unserer*, wohingegen meine bessere Hälfte zu *unsere* tendiert.

Comment: Meinem Sprachgefühl nach richtet sich "in unserer Zeitung einbringen" an Leute, die schon in irgendeiner Weise an der Zeitung beteiligt sind, sich aber bisher nicht (im Sinne dessen, der es sagt oder schreibt) einbringen. Also zum Beispiel könnte es an die Mitarbeiter gerichtet sein, die die Zeitung drucken, layouten oder verteilen, um sie zu ermutigen, auch mal etwas dafür zu schreiben. Auf der anderen Seite würde ich "in unsere Zeitung einbringen" dahingehend interpretieren, dass es vor allem an Leute gerichtet ist, die momentan noch überhaupt nichts mit der Zeitung zu tun haben.

Comment: Ich denke @celtschk hat ein gutes Sprachgefühl. Jetzt, wo ich das gelesen habe, sehe ich das auch so :)

Comment: @celtschk Hmm, das gibt mir ernsthaft zu denken. Es scheint wirklich, dass *unsere* mehr danach klingt, als ob eine Gruppe mit ihrer Zeitung sich an andere, aussenstehende Leute wendet. Sehr eigentartig.

Comment: Ersetzt man *unsere(r)* durch *dem* vs. *den* und macht das Objekt männlich, dann hört es sich für mein Sprachgefühl sehr viel mehr nach dem auch vom Duden gestützten Akkusativ an: *Sie bringt sich den Prozess ein* vs. *Sie bringt sich in dem Prozess ein*. *Sich in dem Prozess einbringen* stürzt doch ganz schön ab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ähnlich wie celtschk in seinem Kommentar schreibt sehe ich es auch. Der Unterschied ist subtil, und die Wiederholung und das "ich" sind gar nicht Thema. Man kann die Frage auf die 2 Sätze reduzieren:

> Bringen Sie sich in unsere Zeitung ein.
>
> Bringen Sie sich in unserer Zeitung ein.

Der Unterschied ist gering. Einmal ist vom Wohin die Rede, das andere Mal vom Wo.

Man kann daraus konstruieren, dass einmal nur eine Entscheidung zu fällen ist, während das andere Mal ein dauerhaftes Engagement ansteht. Ich kann mir aber kaum eine Situation vorstellen, in der man dringend zu einer der zwei Varianten raten würde.

Comment: Für mich erscheint beides möglich. Ich würde sogar Schlüsse aus der je gewählten Version darauf ziehen, wie -möglicherweise- solch ein Engagement gesehen wird - für mich durchaus ein (feines) stilistisches Merkmal bezüglich des Selbstverständnisses dieser Zeitung/dieses Werbers ... *(Ok, gerade noch rechtzeitig zum Nach-editieren fällt mir auf, daß Du das ja im Prinzip auch sagst: daß ein Unterschied existiert, sorry...)*